Is archiving the best solution for duplicates from the Staging Ground?
At the moment, a Staging Ground question that gets enough duplicate votes becomes archived. You can see a list of all such archived questions here. Once a question is archived like this, it gets taken off the SG front page and will not be published on the main site unless it is deliberately approved or edited and improved.
This is great for the kinds of beginner-level duplicates that we get hundreds of each month, but I'm not entirely sure as to whether it's the kind of behavior we want as a blanket-level restriction. After all, some duplicates are good, and letting a few of the better ones graduate might help us cast a wider net.
Is this something we should be concerned about? Is it fine to just let the duplicates stay in the Staging Ground? I'm curious to hear your thoughts.
To be clear, this is not the same question as this recent Meta post. That one's about the technical feasibility of closing a question as a duplicate of a Staging Ground posts. This one's about what we should do as a community with Staging Ground questions that have been closed as a duplicate of a main site post.

Does it work as a workaround to have someone with a gold badge approve the question and then dupe-hammer it again on the main site?

I'm hesitant to post an actual answer, but I'd think the occasional pearl amongst the grains of grubby sand will likely be approved on the merits of being interesting and not obvious duplicates of existing questions; if they are neither, nothing lost, I would say.

Note that for a duplicate to function as a signpost, it needs to survive the roomba. Which effectively means it needs to maintain a positive score, as it can't be answered. I think very few new posts that are clear duplicates from the start actually do that.

I find most duplicates OP should have found by themselves, even just searching for the title they themselves gave their question. Those types of questions get marked as duplicate, and often get downvoted due to clear lack of effort on OP's part. It's very rare to see a duplicate that actually shows some effort (in my experience)

This question is similar to: How should I handle repeat questions in the Staging Ground?. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@computercarguy That’s a technical discussion. This is more of a norms one.

@ErikA Nitpick: it needs to maintain a non-negative score.  Questions closed as duplicate aren't considered "abandoned closed".

@RyanM True, but they're likely to hit the abandoned which does remove questions with a score of 0 afaik. Because they redirect non-logged in users, they're unlikely to hit any of the properties to avoid being considered abandoned I think. Of course, that's except if multiple comments come in.

@ErikA Good point.  It would be rather unlikely to get the views required due to redirecting logged-out users to the target.  Multiple comments might save it, but that's hardly a good general solution.

If a question is getting many views from people getting redirected, I guess there will likely be someone who votes it up even if it's a duplicate.

Graduation for questions that will not receive answers, because they have already been answered, doesn't sound helpful. How am I even supposed to vote on them once it's clear that they are duplicates?
The rationale for not outright deletion of duplicate questions without answers was to basically have different versions for each question on the basis that the original poster did research (really?) and did not find the original duplicate and therefore we need more different versions of the same question (but how many versions are needed and how different do they have to be) so that search engines get more targets to link to. Closing but not deleting them served the goal.
The question would be if additional versions of questions are still needed today? If the new duplicates are for popular questions with already lots of duplicate versions, the asker simply didn't do research, his/her version is likely redundant and not worth keeping. If not, search engines might still have become smarter and better able to understand what people really want to achieve in order to point people to the original version of the question. If the duplicate question in the staging ground would detail how it searched (most new questions don't) then we could maybe reason about how this question is different and bringing a new angle towards the same topic.
I personally would then try to incorporate this really new version into the original version and make a single coherent question (after all it's a duplicate, so answers must remain unaffected). Something like "... or in other words: ...". But this community has historically been strongly against heavy editing, so I won't propose that here.
The remaining options are to either let them die (current situation, archived), promoting them to the old state (approve, publish, close) or inventing a completely new class of content (questions without answers that have only answers elsewhere with a link to elsewhere and cannot be voted upon) as a means to do search engine optimization.
The last option requires work from the side of the company, so rather unlikely. The first two options could be chosen freely. I would tend to argue that there is little to no value in keeping them, so letting them die is the least curation effort later on. Do this for sure for all questions that already have (say) three or more duplicate versions. If we really want to, we can also keep (approve and immediately close) those where no (or not many) versions exist and which sound reasonably different (not just simple rewording). I would use that option sparsely.

so that search engines get more targets to link to. - Not just more, but different.  e.g. the same underlying problem manifesting in different ways, or being described with different words by people with different background experience and who encountered it in different contexts.  The idea is to have different signposts leading the the same set of answers, not primarily out of sympathy for querents who didn't find a duplicate.  If none of the existing duplicates of a question use the same terms to describe a problem and it's overall well asked, it could be a useful additional signpost.

@PeterCordes Fully agreed. That's also how I wanted to describe it. Question is how many truly different contexts there can be about a single topic? We could have some empirical study about that, just look at the last N closed as duplicate questions and see if none of the existing sister duplicate questions use the same terms to describe the problem.

In principle, it would also be possible to publish them as a closed question after e.g. one week of inactivity (or similar) without bumping them to the main question list which I wouldn't consider a distinct class of content.

@dan1st It's a different kind of treatment and would also require action from the company to implement. It might be less work but it's essentially a different kind of content, publishing closed questions that for all likelihood should remain closed forever.

I wouldn't say these should remain closed forever or treated in any different way after publishing (except maybe not bumping them to the question list) so while this would require an implementation change, I don't think the necessary changes would be that big.

@dan1st You mean that closed questions as duplicates often are discovered as not really a duplicate and get reopened. Or at least in a significant number. One could probably make a statistics about it to check.

I think that if necessary, it could be useful but I guess this wouldn't happen in most cases.

Quoting a 14-year-old post by one of the site's founders, created in the site's earliest days, when its landscape was completely different, is not the compelling argument you believe it to be.
Stack Overflow then was a very small and niche site trying to make it big. In that context duplicates made sense because they boosted the SEO score and thus the site's profile. Duplicates then were generally sufficiently high-quality and distinct enough from each other to make them useful signposts.
But it's not 2010 anymore, and Stack Overflow has the opposite problem to what it had back then: too much traffic, rather than too little. The duplicates that get posted today are, by and large, very obvious ones coming from users crafting questions to bypass the dupe-check filters... because doing that is apparently easier than spending the extra 5 seconds to look through the list of probable dupes they're presented with when writing their question.
In 2024 we don't need more duplicates, we need fewer; leave new ones in the Staging Ground to rot. Therefore, the answer to the question posed is "yes".

I think the whole premise of this meta question is that the duplicate in Staging Ground isn't "rubbish" like the 99% of duplicates.

@LWChris And the whole premise of this answer is that new duplicates are rubbish, regardless of whether they come from Staging Ground, the main site, or the man in the moon. I understand how that may not have been clear from my previous wording, so have updated it.

Haha okay, that's a stance/opinion I can understand but do not agree with. :)

This needs to be said more often. Everything is different now. The site is full of questions and answers, way too many of them actually. The site is way more hated because the fuller it is the more the ignored rules start to apply and hurt, it has far less reviewers/curators, feature requests are now ignored and there actually isn't really any narrative anymore between meta and "the company" now that we don't have people like Shog or Tim Post involved. It has far more convoluted rules and new owners with a mission where those rules are a hindrance so they build around them. Everything.
